# $\epsilon$-grid in compact metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

From Zorich, Mathematical Analysis II, pag. 16:

[image]

I believe that lemma 4 is wrongly stated, since if we were actually thinking of a metric space $(K, d)$ with $K$ compact (i.e. such that from any cover of open sets according to the topology induced in $K$ by the metric $d$, it is always possible to extract a finished subcover), I could very well take the following counterexample that violates the proposition:

a set $ K $ consisting of only three real numbers (using the standard metric in $ \mathbb {R} $) $ \Rightarrow K $ is obviously compact but it is equally obvious that the space $ (K, d) $ does not respect the sentence above.

Am I wrong?

Comment: distance $0$ is smaller than $\epsilon$ too... And what makes three numbers special?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are wrong. If $(K,d)$ is a finite metric space, then, for every $\varepsilon>0$ small enough, $K$ itself is a finite $\varepsilon$-grid of $K$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Why do we read "in $X$" in the statement?

Comment: Because a subset $E$ in $X$ is called a $\varepsilon$-grid in $X$ if... Here, @José Carlos Santos choose $X = E = K$.

Comment: Sorry, this point is not clear for me. Written in that way, it seems to me that the lemma says: "if you have a metric space (X,d) in which there is a compact set K, then for the whole set X there exist arbitrary fine grids".

This instead would be more reasonable for me: "if you have a metric space (X,d) in which there is a compact set K, then for the metric subspace (K,d) there exists arbitrary fine grids", that is exactly what the proof shows, if I have understood it correctly.

Comment: No. There is a single space in the statement of the lemma, which is called $K$ and which is compact. There is no space called $X$ there.

Comment: Ok, so the last letter $X$ in the statement of lemma 4 is in fact $K$.
Thanks.

Comment: I missed that $X$, but, yes, it should be $K$.